# Different Behavior for Parsing Two Similar Wikipedia Infoboxes

Tags: python, wikipedia-api

I have two infoboxes that look exactly the same to me, but I'm getting different behavior in mwparserfromhell. In the first instance I'm getting what I expect - the entire infobox is captured as a template object. In the second instance parts of the infobox are extracted as separate templates. This is confusing since the infoboxes look very similar to me, and I was expecting that the entire infobox could be extracted in the second case.

This is the code I'm using:

```
mwparserfromhell.parse(text.strip().lower()).filter_templates()
```

Text 1 Input:

```
txt1 = """{{Infobox building
| name = 666 Fifth Avenue
| former_names = Tishman Building
| status = Complete
| image = 666 Fifth Avenue by David Shankbone.jpg
| image_size = 300px
| caption = 
| location = 666 Fifth Avenue<br>[[Manhattan]], [[New York (state)|New York]] 10103
| coordinates = {{coord|40.760163|-73.976204|format=dms}}
| start_date = 
| completion_date = 1957
| architect = [[Carson & Lundin]]
| owner = [[Brookfield Properties]]
| cost = $40 million
| floor_area = {{convert|1,463,892|sqft|m2|abbr=on}}
| top_floor = 
| floor_count = 41
| references = 
| map_type = 
| building_type = Office
| antenna_spire = 
| roof = {{convert|483|ft|m|abbr=on}}
| elevator_count = 24 (20 passenger, 4 freight)
| structural_engineer = 
| main_contractor = 
| opening = November 25, 1957
| developer = Tishman Realty and Construction
| management = 
}}"""
```

Text 1 Output:

```
['{{infobox building\n| name = 666 fifth avenue\n| former_names = tishman building\n| status = complete\n| image = 666 fifth avenue by david shankbone.jpg\n| image_size = 300px\n| caption = \n| location = 666 fifth avenue<br>[[manhattan]], [[new york (state)|new york]] 10103\n| coordinates = {{coord|40.760163|-73.976204|format=dms}}\n| start_date = \n| completion_date = 1957\n| architect = [[carson & lundin]]\n| owner = [[brookfield properties]]\n| cost = $40 million\n| floor_area = {{convert|1,463,892|sqft|m2|abbr=on}}\n| top_floor = \n| floor_count = 41\n| references = \n| map_type = \n| building_type = office\n| antenna_spire = \n| roof = {{convert|483|ft|m|abbr=on}}\n| elevator_count = 24 (20 passenger, 4 freight)\n| structural_engineer = \n| main_contractor = \n| opening = november 25, 1957\n| developer = tishman realty and construction\n| management = \n}}',
 '{{coord|40.760163|-73.976204|format=dms}}',
 '{{convert|1,463,892|sqft|m2|abbr=on}}',
 '{{convert|483|ft|m|abbr=on}}']
```

Text 2 Input:

```
txt2 = """{{Infobox building
| name = Central Park Tower
| alternate_names = Nordstrom Tower
| image = Central Park Tower April 2020.jpg
| caption = Central Park Tower on April 25, 2020
| location = 225 [[57th Street (Manhattan)|West 57th Street]]<br/>[[Manhattan]], [[New York City]], [[New York (state)|New York]], [[United States|U.S.]]
| coordinates = {{coord|40.7663|-73.9810|type:landmark_globe:earth_region:US-NY|display=inline,title}}
| status = Topped Out
| start_date = 2014
| est_completion = 2020<ref name=curbed>{{cite news |author=Amy Plitt |url=https://ny.curbed.com/2017/6/1/15714666/central-park-tower-offering-plan-approval-sales-launch |title=Central Park Tower is now one step closer to launching sales |date=June 1, 2017 |access-date=August 30, 2017 |work=Curbed}}</ref>
| building_type = [[Residential]], [[retail]]
| architectural_style = [[Modern architecture|Modern]]
| architectural = {{cvt|1550|ft|0}}
| floor_count = 131<ref>{{cite web |url=https://www.architecturaldigest.com/story/new-york-city-central-park-tower-worlds-tallest-residential-building </ref><ref>{{cite web |url=https://archpaper.com/2019/09/central-park-tower-tops-out/</ref> (98 habitable floors)<ref name="auto">{{Cite web |url=http://www.skyscrapercenter.com/building/central-park-tower/14269 |title=Central Park Tower - The Skyscraper Center |website=www.skyscrapercenter.com |access-date=October 10, 2018}}</ref>
| elevator_count = 11
| cost = $3 billion<ref name="Tase">{{cite news|url=https://commercialobserver.com/2019/04/all-in-good-tase-the-crisis-for-the-american-cohort-in-tel-aviv-is-essentially-over/|title=All in Good TASE: The Crisis for the American Cohort in Tel Aviv Is Essentially Over|date=April 4, 2019|work=Commercial Observer|last=Gourarie|first=Chava}}</ref>
| floor_area = {{convert|1,285,308|sqft|m2}}<ref name="auto" />
| architect = [[Adrian Smith + Gordon Gill Architecture]]
| structural_engineer = [[WSP Global]]
| main_contractor = [[Lendlease]]
| developer = [[Extell Development Company]]
}}"""
```

Text 2 Output:

```
['{{coord|40.7663|-73.9810|type:landmark_globe:earth_region:us-ny|display=inline,title}}',
 '{{cite news |author=amy plitt |url=https://ny.curbed.com/2017/6/1/15714666/central-park-tower-offering-plan-approval-sales-launch |title=central park tower is now one step closer to launching sales |date=june 1, 2017 |access-date=august 30, 2017 |work=curbed}}',
 '{{cvt|1550|ft|0}}',
 '{{cite web |url=https://archpaper.com/2019/09/central-park-tower-tops-out/</ref> (98 habitable floors)<ref name="auto">{{cite web |url=http://www.skyscrapercenter.com/building/central-park-tower/14269 |title=central park tower - the skyscraper center |website=www.skyscrapercenter.com |access-date=october 10, 2018}}</ref>\n| elevator_count = 11\n| cost = $3 billion<ref name="tase">{{cite news|url=https://commercialobserver.com/2019/04/all-in-good-tase-the-crisis-for-the-american-cohort-in-tel-aviv-is-essentially-over/|title=all in good tase: the crisis for the american cohort in tel aviv is essentially over|date=april 4, 2019|work=commercial observer|last=gourarie|first=chava}}</ref>\n| floor_area = {{convert|1,285,308|sqft|m2}}<ref name="auto" />\n| architect = [[adrian smith + gordon gill architecture]]\n| structural_engineer = [[wsp global]]\n| main_contractor = [[lendlease]]\n| developer = [[extell development company]]\n}}',
 '{{cite web |url=http://www.skyscrapercenter.com/building/central-park-tower/14269 |title=central park tower - the skyscraper center |website=www.skyscrapercenter.com |access-date=october 10, 2018}}',
 '{{cite news|url=https://commercialobserver.com/2019/04/all-in-good-tase-the-crisis-for-the-american-cohort-in-tel-aviv-is-essentially-over/|title=all in good tase: the crisis for the american cohort in tel aviv is essentially over|date=april 4, 2019|work=commercial observer|last=gourarie|first=chava}}',
 '{{convert|1,285,308|sqft|m2}}']
```

Comment: Sounds like you should simply report a bug at https://github.com/earwig/mwparserfromhell/issues

Comment: Presumably a case of mwparserfromhell not handling `<ref>` tags (self-enclosing ref tags, maybe?) correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug for `mwparserfromhell`. My workaround was to create an on-the-fly regex pattern that would remove the ref link but keep the rest of the text intact.

```
{{ this is text <ref>this is a ref link}}</ref>
```

to

```
{{ this is text }}
```

Here's the code:

```
def get_regex_str_pattern(reg_str):
    """ Creates regex string to remove specific patterns that are embedded in larger strings

    :param reg_str: String to tokenize
    :return: Regex pattern
    """
    return r'.*'.join([f"({re.escape(r.strip())})" for r in reg_str.split()])


def get_ref_clean_str(txt):
    """ Removes badly formed ref strings from wiki text

    :param txt: Wiki text
    :return: Parser object
    """

    clean_txt = txt
    wiki_text = mwparserfromhell.parse(txt)

    for r in wiki_text.filter_tags():
        if str(r.tag) in ('ref', 'br'):
            clean_txt = re.sub(get_regex_str_pattern(r), ' ', clean_txt)

    return mwparserfromhell.parse(clean_txt)
```